# adding Integer objects to a hashSet

Tags: java, set, hashset

Consider the following code:

```
6.  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
7.  Integer i1 = 45;
8.  Integer i2 = 46;
9.  set.add(i1);
10. set.add(i1);
11. set.add(i2); System.out.print(set.size() + " ");
12. set.remove(i1); System.out.print(set.size() + " ");
13. i2 = 47;
14. set.remove(i2); System.out.print(set.size() + " ");
15. System.out.println(set.contains(i2));
```

The code outputs:

`2 1 1 false`

After line 14 I assumed that the size would be `0` but it is `1`. I guess that a new object `i2` is added to the set at line 13, so I tested that at line 15 but it returns `false` (i.e no `i2` exists in the set), why is that?

Comment: You're not modifying the `i2` that's in the set.  You're modifying the reference `i2`; `46` will still be in the set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never actually remove anything from the set on line 14 because you reassign `i2` on the previous line to something different that is not in the set. Try seeing what happens when you remove line 13 altogether.

P.S. The remove method of a set actually returns a boolean, so you can use `System.out.println(set.remove(i2))` to see if `i2` was really removed.

Answer (score 2):

`[45,46]`->  `Remove 45` ->`[46]`->`Remove 47`-> `[46]` As 47 is not present.  Also when you assign i2 with autoboxing reference is changed but hashset still contains old value.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** A Set maintains the **UNIQUENESS of data** in it.

So the `set` after addition of all the data in it was

```
[46, 45]
```

See this trace...

```
[46,45]

set.remove(i1)
```

`[46]`

```
i2 = 47;
set.remove(i2);
```

`[46]`  `// as i2 = 47, but you didn't add it to the set`

so now as `i2 = 47` its **not in the set, so its false.**